# can i insert js codes using out.write method in java

Tags: java

How can i insert javascript in java file. If i am inserting html tags it works fine but if i insert following js code it doesn't show any errors but it will not show the chart also.
i'am using chart.js

```
out.write(""<h1>Graph</h1>\n"");
out.write("<canvas id='canvas' height='450' width='600'></canvas>\n");
out.write("<script>\n");
out.write("var barChartData = \n");
out.write("{labels : ['Pass','Fail'],\n");
out.write("datasets : {\n");
out.write("[fillColor : 'rgba(220,220,220,0.5)',\n");
out.write("strokeColor : 'rgba(220,220,220,1)',\n");
out.write("data : [65,0]},{\n");
out.write("fillColor : 'rgba(151,187,205,0.5)',\n");
out.write("data : [0,47]}]}\n");
out.write("var myLine = new Chart(document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d')).Bar(barChartData);\n");
out.write("</script>\n");
```

Is this is the correct way using out.write ?

Comment: Have you tried adding `<script type='text/javascript'>` ?

Comment: have you tried it, is it runs or gives an error msg???

Comment: is it necessary here to describe script type

Comment: i have tried <script type='text/javascript'> but its also not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [HTML 4 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.2), a `<script>` element *requires* either a `type` or `lang` attribute, unless you have specified the default scripting language.

A document that doesn't conform to this is erroneous, and the browser is free to ignore the script.

---

Another possibility is that your script contains errors.  Use your browser's web developer support to check for javascript errors.

Comment: What does the Javascript console show?  If there are no errors, use the browser's javascript debugger to set a breakpoint and single-step it to see what happens.

Comment: Failed to load resource file:///C:/Users/hsprint.WEB-DESGINER-PC/Downloads/AutomationTestReport_20_Jan_2014_03_12_24_PM/Chart.js

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing to a file on Windows, use `\r\n` instead, because windows filesystem doesn't understands `\n`s as newlines. Else, you must provide more info. It could also be because you missed declarating the script type.

Comment: i have tried declaring the script type but no no results. did i have to use out,write("some code\r\n") instead of out.write("some code\n");

Comment: Javascript doesn't care what type of line terminators you use.  Nor does HTML. Indeed, in a lot of cases, the neither Javacript or HTML require line separators at all.

Comment: Yes but its in most cases. You should avoid.

Comment: thanks but i have found out the problem is not with js its with java